# is there a way in Slick.Grid to render all data to an array so it can be exported?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

Is there a way in Slick.Grid to render all data to an array so it can be exported?

I am able to get the data from my Slick.Grid instance "mygrid.getData().getItems()" but it is just the raw data not the formated data.

Is there a function I can use to iterate though the collection and return the formated data?

As of now I am having to implement my formatters twice.

Example:

```
UnixToDate: (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) ->
  moment.unix(value).format("MMM Do YY")


items: [
   {id: 1, activity_at: 915148798 },
   {id: 2, activity_at: 999148800 }
]

columns: [
    {field: 'id', id: 'id', name: 'Id'},
    {field: 'activity_at', id: 'activity_at', name: 'Activity', formatter: UnixToDate}
]

@data = new Slick.Data.DataView()
@grid = new Slick.Grid( $('#table'), @data, columns )
@data.setItems(items)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to return the data with the formatted values. 
I thought @grid.getData().getItems() would do it but it returns the raw data array.

The data returned should look like:

```
data: [
   {id: 1, activity_at: "Dec 31st 98" },
   {id: 2, activity_at: "Aug 29th 01" }
]
```

I would like the end user to be able to filter and arrange the grid and then export the results in csv format, I have all this working except the formatting part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I wrote a method to do the export (written in coffeescript and using underscore.js).  I also had to expose the getFormatter method in slick.grid.js

```
getFormattedData: (grid) ->
  columns = grid.getColumns()
  rows = grid.getData().getItems()
  _(rows).map (row) ->
    h = {}
    i = 0
    _(columns).each (column) ->
      f = grid.getFormatter(row, column)
      h[column.id] = f(row, i, row[column.id], column, row)
      i += 1
    h
```

add line to slick.grid.js in the // Public API section

```
"getFormatter": getFormatter,
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `autoHeight: true` the complete grid is rendered and the html could be exported.

http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example11-autoheight.html

Answer to updated question:

The formatter is only called when a row is rendered/visible, so an array with the formatted data never exists. At the source: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L1291

Comment: rendering all the data then parsing the html could work but it would not be efficient at all. I am going through the slick.grid.js file there must be a way to call the format function on the data array.

Comment: i don't understand, you write that you want the formated data, what do you mean by that if not the html?

Comment: i am talking about the javascript array that is used to populate the grid. I have added an example to my question..